# Scrollview can only host one child

Tags: android

I can't figure out how to get these radio groups/text views into a scrollview. Can anyone help me? Heres what i've tried but I keep getting the error scrollview can only host one child and I don't know how to fix it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ContactSettingsActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/navbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/navbar_background" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButtonMap"
            android:src="@drawable/contactlisticon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonMap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/mapicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButtonMap"
            android:src="@drawable/settingsicon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/navbar">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Sort Contact By:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Name" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioCity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBirthday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Birthday" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Sort Order:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioAscending"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Ascending" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioDescending"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Descending" />

    </RadioGroup>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a single container layout for all the child items you want to appear in a ScrollView.  Most of the time this will be a LinearLayout to get them stacked vertically, but it could really be any view you want.  You just need to choose one and arrange the children in it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Add a layout inside scroll view and move the ui widgets(textview and radiogroup) inside that layout.